# How to redirect urls with domain inside my domain in php

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have a login system with previous page redirection after successful login.
For example, if user enters login.php?redirect=https://www.google.com, It would redirect to https://www.google.com.

I want it to redirect to https://www.example.com/https://www.google.com.

(Example.com is my domain.)

How can I do this?

What I've already tried:

```
header("Location: /". $_POST["redirect_url"]);
```

And

```
header("Location: https://www.example.com/". $_POST["redirect_url"]);
```

But if it is **/page**, it redirects to **https://www.example.com//page**, with the double slashes.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you test it? `header("Location: https://www.example.com/" . $_POST["redirect_url"]);`

Comment: your using `redirect` and `redirect_url`, which is it? You can do `header("Location: ". $_REQUEST["redirect"]);`

Comment: @MohammadrezaYektamaram, I tested it also

Comment: I mentioned // double slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could detect and remove the leading slash from your $_POST.

```
if (preg_match('~^\/~', $_POST['redirect_url'])) {
    $_POST['redirect_url'] = substr($_POST['redirect_url'], 1);
}
```

Comment: I also works with ////////page urls, it completely works!!